# Conditional Formating with UDF block Worksheet_change execution

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel file which has to be printed later, however I was trying to create macro wchich will check, if whole cell content is visible. Long story short, code below is copying cell value to a temporary cell and if it can be fitted with adjusting only row height it does it, if column width is required to be changed it marking it with colour (.interior.colorindex). [code below]. And it works perfectly, but at the same time in the sheet I'm using conditional formating for creating "table", for better data visibility (I cannot use standard table for various reasons). As you may know, standard conditional formating cannot be overwritten, that's why I created UDF and used it in conditional formating formula.

```
Function TestColor(MyRange As Range) As Boolean
Application.Volatile
If Range(MyRange.Address).Interior.Pattern = xlNone Then
    TestColor = True
Else
    TestColor = False
End If
End Function
```

Also, it working as intended, but Worksheet_change stoped working at the same time. Separately both codes work perfectly, together only UDF in conditional formating is working.
Do you have any idea how modify this to start working or any work around for similar case?

**EDIT:**
If I change value outside conditional formating range, "Fits" procedure works correctly, so it looks like UDF reference is actively blocking "Fits" to proceed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 call Fits(Target)
End sub

Sub Fits(ByVal Range As Range)
Dim cell As Range, tmp_cell As Range, da As Boolean, su As Boolean Wrap as string
'Stores current state and disables ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts
su = Application.ScreenUpdating: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
da = Application.DisplayAlerts: Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Creates a new worksheet and uses first cell as temporary cell
Set tmp_cell = Worksheets("TemporaryTEST").Cells(1, 1)
Wrap= Range.Wraptext
'Enumerate all cells in Range
For Each cell In Range.Cells
    'Copy cell to temporary cell
    cell.Copy tmp_cell
    'Copy cell value to temporary cell, if formula was used
    If cell.HasFormula Then tmp_cell.Value = cell.Value
    'Checking depends on WrapText
    Select Case Wrap
        Case "True", "Null"
            'Ensure temporary cell column is equal to original
            tmp_cell.ColumnWidth = cell.ColumnWidth
            tmp_cell.EntireRow.AutoFit 'Force fitting
            If tmp_cell.RowHeight > cell.RowHeight Then 'Cell doesn't fit!
                If tmp_cell.RowHeight = 409.5 Then
                    tmp_cell.EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Force fitting
                    If tmp_cell.ColumnWidth > cell.ColumnWidth Then 'Cell doesn't fit!
                        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
                'row extension needed
                cell.RowHeight = tmp_cell.RowHeight
                Exit For 'Exit For loop (at least one cell doesn't fit)
            End If
        Case "False"
            tmp_cell.EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Force fitting
            If tmp_cell.ColumnWidth > cell.ColumnWidth Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
                Exit For 'Exit For loop (at least one cell doesn't fit)
            End If
    End Select
Next
tmp_cell.Value = ""
tmp_cell.Columns.UseStandardWidth = True
tmp_cell.Rows.UseStandardHeight = True
'Restore ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts state
Application.DisplayAlerts = da
Application.ScreenUpdating = su
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CalculateFull
End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional formating formula is as below
    =AND(MOD(ROW(A1),2)=0, TestColor(A1))

Comment: Quite possibly not the cause of your problems, but I would not call a variable `Range`.

Comment: @SJR thanks, corrected it and still issue is present. (I'm trying to avoid this kind of naming however, this part of the code was copied from a different topic on StackOverflow and adapted)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is worksheet_Change not triggrered?

Comment: @jkpieterse It's hard to say because breakpoints stopped working inside Worksheet_change procedure, when I entered Msgbox at the begging of Worksheet_change it poping up. But "Fits" do not work as intended( do not adjust height or color cells). I entered also Msgbox into "Fits", but it wasn't triggered(EnableEvents blocked this?), however debug.print worked.
As soon as, I comment block UDF (TestColor), "Fits" start working correctly and breakpoints also.
By "Fits" working I mean that was triggered from Worksheet_change procedure and outcome was as intended.

I hope this help.

Comment: What is worth mentioning, if I change value outside conditional formating range then everything works. It looks like UDF is actively blocking other procedures.

Comment: What happens if you turn off calculation in your change event and subsequent routines? Those may trigger your UDF to recalculate. Debugging a workbook which makes use of lots of calls to UDFs can be very tricky. I always advise against using colors as an indication of a value, better to use a value entered into a cell so you can omit the UDF altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing calculation yo manual had no impact on Worksheet_change event. I assume that conditional formating isn't impacted by calculation status. Probably I will need to apply on change event for applying  formating, instead of using conditional formating.